# How to update TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE columns with value of particular zone?

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I have a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column in my table.
I want to update all values with systimestamp at their respective timezones.

I have tried many ways, but i could not dynamically get timezone information from the value and update the same in a single query.

I will provide the necessary structure here.

```
create table TIMEZONE_TEST
( COLUMN_ONE timestamp with time zone
);

insert into TIMEZONE_TEST values (systimestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific');
insert into TIMEZONE_TEST values (systimestamp at time zone 'Asia/Tokyo');
insert into TIMEZONE_TEST values (systimestamp at time zone 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
insert into TIMEZONE_TEST values (systimestamp at time zone 'Asia/Singapore');
commit;
```

I need to update all values with systimestamp of particular timezones.

something like

```
update TIMEZONE_TEST
set COLUMN_ONE = systimestamp at time zone '<TIMEZONE_NAME of the value>';
```

Thanks for the kind help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required answer was

```
UPDATE TIMEZONE_TEST
SET COLUMN_ONE = SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM COLUMN_ONE);
```

I modified the answer given by @Wernfried.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I got your question properly but I assume it should be this one:

```
UPDATE TIMEZONE_TEST SET 
COLUMN_ONE = FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP), EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM COLUMN_ONE));
```

Comment: the query that is provided inserts systimestamp at server timezone and also the timezone information from the previous value. however I need SYSTIMESTAMP AT that previous value' s TIMEZONE to be inserted. i.e. during insert, the HH:MI values are different, However after running your query, all HH:MI are all the same.

Comment: `UPDATE TIMEZONE_TEST SET 
COLUMN_ONE = SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM COLUMN_ONE);`  works just fine for my scenario. and is the answer. Thanks @Wernfried